Node.js IMAP Error: Connection Ending Unexpectedly
Here I crawl email for every 10 minutes to updatemy DB, but i am facing problem with last 4 emails, during which my imap connection closes, and hence it do not perform that operation.

export const readAllEmailReports = async () => {   try {
let visitedData = {};

const imap = new Imap(imapConfig);

const yesterday = moment().subtract(5, "hour").toDate();

imap.once("ready", () => {
  imap.openBox("INBOX", false, () => {
    imap.search(
      [
        "ALL",
        // "UNSEEN",
        ["FROM", "test@test.com"],
        [
          "OR",
          ["SUBJECT", "Complete_Report"],
          ["SUBJECT", "Partial_Report"],
        ],
        ["SINCE", yesterday],
      ],
      (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }

        if (results.length === 0) {
          console.log("No new messages to fetch.");
          imap.end();
          return;
        }

        const f = imap.fetch(results, { bodies: "" });
        f.on("message", async (msg) => {
          msg.on("body", async (stream) => {
            simpleParser(stream, async (err, parsed) => {
              if (err) {
                console.error("Error parsing email:", err);
                throw err;
              }

              const text = parsed.text ? parsed.text : parsed.html;
              const parsedText = extractVidInfo(text, parsed?.subject);

              if (
                !visitedData[
                  parsedText.visitNumber + "-" + parsedText.reportType
                ]
              ) {
                // console.log("inserting");

                // If the visit number doesn't exist in the map, create a new entry
                visitedData[
                  parsedText.visitNumber + "-" + parsedText.reportType
                ] = {
                  visitNumber: parsedText?.visitNumber,
                  reportType: parsedText?.reportType,
                  subject: parsed?.subject,
                  // text: text,
                  attachments: [],
                };

                if (parsed.attachments && parsed.attachments.length > 0) {
                  for (let attachment of parsed.attachments) {
                    if (isSupportedAttachment(attachment))
                      visitedData[
                        parsedText.visitNumber + "-" + parsedText.reportType
                      ].attachments.push(attachment);
                  }
                }
              } else {
                console.log(
                  "not inserting",
                  parsedText.visitNumber,
                  "----",
                  parsedText.reportType
                );
              }
            });
          });
        });

        f.once("error", (ex) => {
          console.error(ex);
        });
        f.once("end", async () => {
          const processingTasks = Object.entries(visitedData).map(async ([key, visitData]) => {
             "some complex logic"
           
          });
          if (processingTasks.length > 0) {
            await Promise.all(processingTasks);
          }
          console.log("Done fetching all messages!");
          imap.end();
        });
      }
    );
  });
});

imap.once("error", (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

imap.once("end", () => {
  console.log("Connection ended");
});

imap.connect();   } catch (ex) {
console.error("An error occurred", ex);   } };


Here I loop visiteData to perform some checks and update the db, but when it is at the end of operation, imap connection closes suddenly

what's in your imapConfig ? connTimeout has a 10seconds default value

But it takes more than minute to execute function, and only last 4 will get rejected out of 150.
